# Is there a correct way to turn off UAC, User Account Control, in Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, uac

Is there a correct way to turn off UAC, User Account Control, in Windows Server 2008?

I have found [an article at Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772207%28WS.10%29.aspx) explaining the various settings. It looks like it is just a matter of disabling "User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode", but I wanted a second opinion.

Comment: I understand the implications of turning UAC off. And am only considering this for a very particular situation, on a test/development server.

Comment: OK, then. Some people disable UAC just because "is annoying". I my opinion is an essential feature nowadays from a security point of view, since the AV detect rate is quite low from several years ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, just use that setting, but in my opinion the correct way of turning off UAC is leaving it enabled :-), at least once the server is configured and all required applications installed.

Using an option provided by the Windows interface or by Group Policy is better in almost all situations than using a registry hack.